# jQuery Horizontal Not Works on AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, scroll

I have a Music Website where i need playlist to be scrolled horizontally using [this plugin](http://www.htmldrive.net/items/demo_show/966). when I'm using it on static page it works perfectly but when i am use it in div where contents are loaded via Ajax it does not work (users adding music to playlist and its appears to this div). The code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body #playlist').horizontalScroll();    
});
```

what to add in this js code to make it workable while content gets loaded via ajax too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're replacing the `#playlist` element after the AJAX call completes you'll need to re-initialise the plugin on the new `#playlist` element in the success callback function, something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    // some AJAX options
}).done(function(data) {
    // do something with data (your response)
    $('#playlist').horizontalScroll();
});
```

If you have more than one AJAX request that could potentially require the plugin to be re-initialised you may want to consider the [`ajaxSuccess`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/) event:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
    $('#playlist').horizontalScroll();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try calling that:

```
$('body #playlist').horizontalScroll();
```

after the ajax call has finished. Or check if that component has some update method in it.